# Alfresco user activity log

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Who knows where can I find user activity log in Alfresco Community v5.1.

I did not find this type of info in alfresco.log or share.log.

I think user activity log should be saved in DB but I did not find any tables which contain this type of info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable audit for logging this kind of information.Below link will help you in enabling audit in alfresco.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-enable.html.

There are few addons available on alfresco , using which you can see this information in alfresco share.

There are few rest services available using which you can fetch this details.

I guess once you enable audit, you will find things in database as well.

Comment: You might find interesting data in your access_logs too, but indeed the audit mecanism is the way to go.

Comment: There you can find more detail explanation about audit log - http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-audit.html

Comment: I have activated audits in alfresco-global.properties. But nothing changed. I have still can't find any info (about user activity) in alfresco.log, share.log or even in DB.